# I tried to fetch bulkcollect records from sys_refcursor and tried to insert another table using forall but it throw an error message

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, plsql-package

--My first procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P1(V_SALARY NUMBER,OUTPUT_VALUE OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN OUTPUT_VALUE FOR 
  SELECT FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME
    FROM EMPLOYEES
   WHERE SALARY >V_SALARY;
END;
```

--Second procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P2(V_SAL NUMBER)
AS
RETURN_VALUE SYS_REFCURSOR;
  TYPE TTT IS RECORD(FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(30),LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(20)) ;
  I TTT;
  TYPE TNAME IS TABLE OF TTT INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  K TNAME;
BEGIN
  P1(V_SAL,RETURN_VALUE);
  FETCH RETURN_VALUE BULK COLLECT INTO K;
  FORALL X IN K.FIRST..K.LAST 
    INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (K(X).FIRST_NAME,K(X).LAST_NAME);
  CLOSE RETURN_VALUE;
END;
/
```

> ERROR at line 12: PLS-00436: implementation restriction: cannot reference fields of BULK In-BIND table of records

but if i tried to insert for loop then it is working fine..It is not working when i use Forall(bulk bind)

Comment: Let me know if following works: `INSERT INTO T1 VALUES K(X);`

Comment: No..it doesn't work @Tejash

Comment: help me to solve @Moudiz

Comment: Is it throwing the same error??

Comment: No..differencet error--ERROR at line 12: PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

Comment: What is your Oracle version? [PLS-00436](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=410) sounds like Oracle 10g.

Comment: By the way, [indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) is a useful technique for making your code readable. Also, [you don't have to use caps-lock to write code](https://queenofcobol.com/uppercase-lowercase/) and [all-capitals make text harder to read](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/72622).

Comment: yes oracle10g is my version @WilliamRobertson

Comment: You have to create a RECORD table instead of SYS_REFCURSOR in P2 procedure. See this link please:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48290631/fetch-and-bulk-collect-from-sys-refcursor-from-another-procedure-and-insert-into

Comment: Also you have to replace PROCEDURE P2 by FUNCTION P2, or to use RETURN_VALUE as OUT parameter if you want to keep PROCEDURE P2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like some bug or restriction when you try to do bulk binding while returning `collection` or `sys_refcursor` from another Procedure. 
However, you have many other options rather bulk binding (Looping using `FORALL`) which are equally performant.

Alternative are as below:

Table Preparation:

```
Create table employees (
  first_name   varchar2(100),
  last_name    varchar2(100),
  salary       number
);

Insert into employees values('A','B',1000);
Insert into employees values('C','D',2000);
Insert into employees values('E','F',3000);


Create table t1 (
  first_name   varchar2(100),
  last_name    varchar2(100)  
);

--Using Objects in place of records and sys_refcursor.
Create or replace type return_value is Object (
  first_name   varchar2(100),
  last_name    varchar2(100)  
);

Create or replace  type v_ret_val is table of return_value;
```

Option 1: Declaring `P1` as `Function` and then using collection as direct path insert.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function p1 (v_salary NUMBER)      
 return v_ret_val
  AS
  abc v_ret_val;
BEGIN
  SELECT return_value(first_name,last_name) 
  Bulk collect into
    abc
  FROM employees
  WHERE salary > v_salary;

 Return abc;
END;
---------------    
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p2 (
      v_sal NUMBER
    ) AS
      k   v_ret_val;
    BEGIN     

      k:=p1(v_sal);

      --Displaying values of collection
      For i in 1..k.count
      Loop
        dbms_output.put_line(k(i).first_name || k(i).last_name);
      End Loop;

      --Direct path insert
      INSERT /*+Append*/ INTO t1
      Select t.first_name,t.last_name
      from (table( k )) t;
      COMMIT;
    END;
```

Option 2: Declaring `P1` as `procedure` with `OUT` parameter and then using collection as direct path insert.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure p11 (
  v_salary NUMBER
  ,output_value OUT v_ret_val
) 
AS  
BEGIN
  SELECT return_value(first_name,last_name) 
  Bulk collect into
    output_value
  FROM employees
  WHERE salary > v_salary;

END;
------------------------------

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p2 ( v_sal NUMBER) 
AS
  k   v_ret_val;
BEGIN
  p11(v_sal,k);     

  For i in 1..k.count
  Loop
    dbms_output.put_line(k(i).first_name || k(i).last_name);
  End Loop;

  INSERT /*+Append*/ INTO t1
  Select t.first_name,t.last_name
  from (table( k )) t;

END;
```

Option 3: Declaring `P1` as `procedure` with `OUT` parameter and then `Merging` the collection with target Table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p2 (
  v_sal NUMBER
) AS
  k   v_ret_val;
BEGIN
  p11(v_sal,k);     

  For i in 1..k.count
  Loop
    dbms_output.put_line(k(i).first_name || k(i).last_name);
  End Loop;  

MERGE INTO t1 tgt 
  Using ( Select t.first_name,
                                   t.last_name
                            from table ( k ) t
                          ) src
  on (
    tgt.first_name = src.first_name 
    and tgt.last_name = src.first_name
    )
  When not matched 
  then 
   insert (
           tgt.first_name,
           tgt.last_name
         ) 
   values (
            src.first_name,
            src.last_name
          );     
END;
```

Execution:

```
 Exec P2(1000);
```

Output:

```
SQL> Select * from t1;

    FIRST_NAME                         LAST_NAME
    -------------------------------------------
    E                                     F
    C                                     D
```